# std::pair and auto substitution in visual studio 2010

Tags: c++

I use the following codes to illustrate my question:

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int abc[8]={3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6}; 
    std::vector<int> v(abc,abc+8);
    ;
    std::pair<int,int>  v2(std::minmax_element(v.begin(),v.end()));



    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

If I compile the above codes, I will have the following compilation errors with visual studio:

```
Error   2   error C2439: 'std::_Pair_base<_Ty1,_Ty2>::first' : member could not be initialized  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\utility  163
Error   4   error C2439: 'std::_Pair_base<_Ty1,_Ty2>::second' : member could not be initialized C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\utility  163
Error   1   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>' to 'int'  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\utility  163
Error   3   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>' to 'int'  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\utility  163
```

The compilation errors will disapper if I use auto key word:

```
auto v2 = std::minmax_element(v.begin(),v.end());
```

Then here is my question: how I can use `std::pair<int,int>` variable properly to substitue `auto` key word?

Comment: I don't know about VS 2010, but in VS 2012 if I hold the mouse over v2 in the `auto` declaration, it is showing the actual type in a tooltip (which is not a pair of `int`, as you can see in the answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::minmax_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) returns a pair of `ForwardIterator`<sup>1</sup> (same type as its arguments), so if you want a pair of `int` you need two steps:

```
auto v2_it = std::minmax_element(v.begin(), v.end());
// You should check here if v2_it.first != v.end()
std::pair<int, int> v2(*v2_it.first, *v2_it.second);
```

Note that `auto` here is actually:

```
std::pair<std::vector<int>::iterator, std::vector<int>::iterator>
```

<sub><sup>1</sup> Most algorithms from the standard library works with and returns iterators (except some specific to `std::string`).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the function signature for minmax_element (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element), it doesn't return a pair of objects. It returns a pair of iterators. So you need your `std::pair` to have the same type as what auto deduced (a pair of iterators)